# Subscribing a batch of email addresses in MailGun via API

Tags: php, mailgun

When sending a batch of new email addresses to subscribe to my mailing list, I get a fatal error.

I borrowed the code from the example under "Add multiple mailing list members (limit 1,000 per call)" on Mailgun's API documentation at  https://documentation.mailgun.com/en/latest/api-mailinglists.html#examples
and my array looks like the example.

My array:

```
array:2 [▼
  "members" => array:1 [▼
    0 => "[{"name":"Someone","address":"sub1@example.com","vars":"{\"subscriber_id\":33}"},{"name":"Ellem","address":"sub2@example.com","vars":"{\"subscriber_id\":34}"},{"name":"Enno","address":"sub3@example.com","vars":"{\"subscriber_id\":35}"},{"name":"Nick","address":"sub4@example.com","vars":"{\"subscriber_id\":36}"},{"name":"Carl","address":"sub5@example.com","vars":"{\"subscriber_id\":37}"},{"name":"Tammy","address":"sub6@example.com","vars":"{\"subscriber_id\":38}"},{"name":"Janis","address":"sub7@example.com","vars":"{\"subscriber_id\":39}"}]"
  ]
  "upsert" => true
]
```

and the call I'm making:

```
$mgClient = new Mailgun($MAILGUN_SECRET);
$result = $mgClient->post("lists/$listAddress/members.json", $myarray);
```

I get the following error:

> First argument to Stream::create() must be a string, resource or StreamInterface. {"userId":1,"email":"sub1@example.com","exception":"[object] (InvalidArgumentException(code: 0): First argument to Stream::create() must be a string, resource or StreamInterface. at /home/SECRET.cloudwaysapps.com/SECRET/public_html/vendor/nyholm/psr7/src/Stream.php:87)

Here's the part of the stack trace that seems relevant:

> /home/SECRET.cloudwaysapps.com/SECRET/public_html/vendor/nyholm/psr7/src/Factory/HttplugFactory.php(29):
>   Nyholm\Psr7\Stream::create(true)
>
> `#1`
>   /home/SECRET.cloudwaysapps.com/SECRET/public_html/vendor/php-http/multipart-stream-builder/src/MultipartStreamBuilder.php(61):
>   Nyholm\Psr7\Factory\HttplugFactory->createStream(true)
>
> `#2`
>   /home/SECRET.cloudwaysapps.com/SECRET/public_html/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php(98):
>   Http\Message\MultipartStream\MultipartStreamBuilder->addResource('upsert',
>   true, Array)
>
> `#3`
>   /home/SECRET.cloudwaysapps.com/SECRET/public_html/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Connection/RestClient.php(179):
>   Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->send('POST', 'lists/devtest@n...',
>   Array, Array)
>
> `#4`
>   /home/SECRET.cloudwaysapps.com/SECRET/public_html/vendor/mailgun/mailgun-php/src/Mailgun/Mailgun.php(208):
>   Mailgun\Connection\RestClient->post('lists/devtest@n...', Array,
>   Array)
>
> `#5`
>   /home/SECRET.cloudwaysapps.com/SECRET/public_html/app/Http/Controllers/SubscribersController.php(591):
>   Mailgun\Mailgun->post('lists/devtest@n...', Array)
>
> `#6` [internal function]:
>   App\Http\Controllers\SubscribersController->processUpload(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request))

I would appreciate any guidance on where I went wrong. Was I supposed to CREATE and ATTACH the members.json file?

Comment: can you please add all code you write for sending those emails ?

Comment: My send code works great. I'm not having trouble with sending via Mailgun. The problem is with adding members to the mailing list in batch (I'm uploading a CSV).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not get it to work using the post method. Another person had trouble with a different post command, and the advice was to use the helpers, for which documentation is difficult to find. But I cobbled together this solution:

First, I created an array for the new members:

```
$sarray = [];
$sarray["name"] = $name;
$sarray["address"] = $email;
$sarray["vars"] = array('subscriber_id'=>$id);
```

and bundled them into an array of member arrays, `$combinedarray`

Then I called the createMultiple method:

```
    $mgClient = Mailgun::create($MAILGUN_API_KEY);
    $result = $mgClient->mailingList()->member()->createMultiple($listaddress,$combinedarray,'no');
```

The $result was an UpdateResponse object, which has a public getMessage method, so
`$message = $result->getMessage();`

got me what I needed. Seems simple now that I've boiled it down, but FINDING this info was the challenge! (I think Mailgun is in the process of updating the API and docs, so this solution might be much more easily found in the docs soon.)